# React passing data from child component to parent component

Tags: reactjs

I am using a material UI Auto-suggest component and i would like to pass the full name to the parent component. This link is similar to my code https://codesandbox.io/s/ryn76v485m

The parent component is passing down the emailUser props

```
<SearchForUsers emailUser={this.emailUsers}/>

emailUsers = (user) => {
    debugger
     console.log(user + "trying to pass down from child")
  }
```

The problem that i am having is that i cannot get the child component to pass the state correctly to the parent component.

At the moment i am doing the this.props.emailUser(this.state.values) after the mapping of the employees. The state is only change after the second person has been entered. I tried putting the this.props.emailUser into the onChange but that event does not update the state when the user clicks on the suggested name. Can anyone tell me how to do get the state back to the parent component correctly.

This is my child component.

```
class ShareForUsers extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menuOpen: false,
      value: "",
      values: []
    };
  }

    componentDidMount() {
    if (!!this.props.employees && this.props.employees.length == 0) {
       this.props.listEmployees();
      }
    }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ ...nextProps })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          value={this.state.value}
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: this.state.values
              .concat()
              .sort(({ label: aLabel }, { label: bLabel }) => {
                if (aLabel < bLabel) return -1;
                else if (aLabel > bLabel) return 1;
                return 0;
              })
              .map(chip => (
                <InputAdornment
                  component={Chip}
                  label={chip}

                  onDelete={() => {
                    const value = chip;
                    this.setState(({ values: prevValues }) => {
                      const values = prevValues;
                      const idx = values.indexOf(value);
                      if (idx === -1) {
                        values.push(value);
                      } else {
                        values.splice(idx, 1);
                      }
                      return {
                        values
                      };
                    });
                  }}
                />
              ))
          }}
          onChange={evt => {
            const value = evt.target.value;
            this.setState({
              value,
              menuOpen: value.length > 0
            });
          }}
          onFocus={() =>
            this.setState(({ value }) => ({
              menuOpen: value.length > 0

            }))

          }
          onBlur={() => this.setState({})}
        />
        <div>
          {this.state.menuOpen ? (
            <Paper
              style={{
                position: "absolute",
                zIndex: 100,
                width: "100%"
              }}
            >
            {this.props.employees
                .filter(
                  employee =>
                  employee.user.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.value) > -1
                )
                .map(employee => (
                  <MenuItem
                    key={employee.user.id}
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.setState(({ values: prevValues }) => {
                        const values = prevValues.concat();
                        const idx = values.indexOf(employee.user.id);
                        if (idx === -1) {
                          values.push(employee.user.email);
                        } else {
                          values.splice(idx, 1);
                        }
                        return {
                          values,
                          value: "",
                          menuOpen: false
                        };
                      });
                    }}
                  >
                    {employee.user.email}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Paper>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const shareForUsers = withStyles(styles)(ShareForUsers)
export default connect(
  state => state.user,
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(shareForUsers);
```

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Create function in parent to pass to child props that can be called in `onChange` or whatever event handlers you need

Comment: please provide the sandbox code to help you better.

Comment: this is similar to the code that i have https://codesandbox.io/s/ryn76v485m

Answer (score 0):

In onChange event you can pass the value from SearchForUsers component to its parent by this:

```
onChange={evt => {
        const value = evt.target.value;
        this.setState({
          value,
          menuOpen: value.length > 0
        });
        this.props.emailUser(value);
      }}
```

Comment: this only updates the state when you type. when you click on the suggested name it does not update the state then.

Comment: okay, in that case here is the workaround `onBlur={() => { this.setState({});  setTimeout(() => {this.props.emailUser(this.state.values)},0);}}` . in `setTimeout`  `this.state.values` will be an array of all selected values. If you want to get the latest selected object then make a copy of `this.state.values` before `setTimeout` and in `setTimeout function` take the difference of copy and this.state.values that will give you the recent object... hope you get the idea.

Comment: `this.sate.values` is an array of objects. If you want to pass only the values then do this `this.props.emailUser(this.state.values.map(obj => obj.value))`

Comment: I put the this.props.emailUser into the InputAdorment. The whole value gets send to the parent component. I also had to check if the user-email exists in the parent because every time you click on the text field it calls the parent method. Probably not the best way of doing it but it works. Another issue is that it does not delete the values so i commented that out for the moment

    <InputAdornment
    component={Chip}
    label={chip}
    onChange={this.props.emailUser(chip)}
    />